# How to set menu bar color in win32?

Tags: winapi, menu, menubar, nonclient-area

I need to set all the non-client areas of my app (border, caption, menu bar) to a specific color.

I can set the caption and border with DwmSetWindowAttribute.  But the menu bar eludes me.

I try creating a brush and using SetMenuInfo like this:

```
LOGBRUSH lbr;
memset(&lbr, 0, sizeof(LOGBRUSH));
lbr.lbColor = RGB(200,0,0);
HBRUSH GBRUSH = CreateBrushIndirect(&lbr);
// Apply Brush to the Menu
MENUINFO mi = { 0 }; 
memset(&mi, 0, sizeof(MENUINFO));
mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi); 
GetMenuInfo(GetMenu(), &mi);
mi.fMask = MIM_BACKGROUND | MIM_APPLYTOSUBMENUS;
mi.hbrBack = GBRUSH;
BOOL bRet = SetMenuInfo(GetMenu(), &mi);
```

... but that affects only the popup submenus, not the menu bar itself.

I found advice to use SetWindowTheme to disable the theme; that works, and allows me to then set the menu bar color BUT then I can no longer set the caption and border.

Short of going full owner-draw on the entire menu, is there a way I can use these (or other) APIs to set all the non-client regions?

Comment: You means this?https://i.stack.imgur.com/E54jL.png

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.  And I can, as per the code I posted - but only if I call SetWindowTheme to disable themes.   And if I do that I can no longer set the caption and border colors with DwmSetWindowAttribute.   So it seems I can set the menu color OR the caption/border color, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

### Using undocumented Windows messages and structures to custom menubar.

[image]

- 0x0091 `WM_UAHDRAWMENU` This message is sent to draw the menu bar
  background. The `LPARAM` is a UAHMENU pointer.

  Draw the background into hdc. The menu bar rect can be calculated by
  using `GetMenuBarInfo` to get the rcBar, `GetWindowRect` to get the
  window rect, and then `OffsetRect(rcBar, -rcWindow.left, -rcWindow.top).`
- 0x0092 `WM_UAHDRAWMENUITEM` This message is sent to draw an
  individual menu item. The `LPARAM` is a `UAHDRAWMENUITEM` pointer.

  The zero-based position of the menu item is in `umi.iPosition`. Draw
  the background and text into `um.hdc` using the rectangle in
  `dis.rcItem`. The state of the menu item is in `dis.itemState`,
  generally a combination of any `(ODS_DEFAULT | ODS_INACTIVE | ODS_HOTLIGHT | ODS_SELECTED | ODS_GRAYED | ODS_DISABLED | ODS_NOACCEL)`
- 0x0094 `WM_UAHMEASUREMENUITEM` This message is sent to measure an
  individual menu item. The LPARAM is a `UAHMEASUREMENUITEM` pointer.

  Forwarding this to `DefWindowProc` will fill in the values as
  expected, which is all you need if you are simply changing background
  colors or etc and not messing with the width. The `MEASUREITEMSTRUCT`
  is intended to be filled in with the size of the text.

This is a sample Based on VS windows desktop application.
This is the menubarsample.cpp:

```
#include "framework.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "UAHMenuBar.h"
#include <Uxtheme.h>
#include <vsstyle.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "uxtheme.lib")
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_MENUBARSAMPLE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MENUBARSAMPLE));
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MENUBARSAMPLE));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_MENUBARSAMPLE);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));
    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }
   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);
   return TRUE;
}
static HTHEME g_menuTheme = nullptr;

// ugly colors for illustration purposes
static HBRUSH g_brBarBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(200, 0, 0));

void UAHDrawMenuNCBottomLine(HWND hWnd)
{
    MENUBARINFO mbi = { sizeof(mbi) };
    if (!GetMenuBarInfo(hWnd, OBJID_MENU, 0, &mbi))
    {
        return;
    }
    RECT rcClient = { 0 };
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
    MapWindowPoints(hWnd, nullptr, (POINT*)&rcClient, 2);

    RECT rcWindow = { 0 };
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rcWindow);
    OffsetRect(&rcClient, -rcWindow.left, -rcWindow.top);
    // the rcBar is offset by the window rect
    RECT rcAnnoyingLine = rcClient;
    rcAnnoyingLine.bottom = rcAnnoyingLine.top;
    rcAnnoyingLine.top--;

    HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hWnd);
    FillRect(hdc, &rcAnnoyingLine, g_brBarBackground);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
}
bool UAHWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* lr)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_UAHDRAWMENU:
    {
        UAHMENU* pUDM = (UAHMENU*)lParam;
        RECT rc = { 0 };
        // get the menubar rect
        {
            MENUBARINFO mbi = { sizeof(mbi) };
            GetMenuBarInfo(hWnd, OBJID_MENU, 0, &mbi);

            RECT rcWindow;
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rcWindow);
            // the rcBar is offset by the window rect
            rc = mbi.rcBar;
            OffsetRect(&rc, -rcWindow.left, -rcWindow.top);
        }
        FillRect(pUDM->hdc, &rc, g_brBarBackground);
        return true;
    }
    case WM_UAHDRAWMENUITEM:
    {
        UAHDRAWMENUITEM* pUDMI = (UAHDRAWMENUITEM*)lParam;
        // ugly colors for illustration purposes
        static HBRUSH g_brItemBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 200, 0));
        static HBRUSH g_brItemBackgroundHot = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 200));
        static HBRUSH g_brItemBackgroundSelected = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(100, 100, 0));

        HBRUSH* pbrBackground = &g_brItemBackground;
        // get the menu item string
        wchar_t menuString[256] = { 0 };
        MENUITEMINFO mii = { sizeof(mii), MIIM_STRING };
        {
            mii.dwTypeData = menuString;
            mii.cch = (sizeof(menuString) / 2) - 1;

            GetMenuItemInfo(pUDMI->um.hmenu, pUDMI->umi.iPosition, TRUE, &mii);
        }
        // get the item state for drawing
        DWORD dwFlags = DT_CENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER;
        int iTextStateID = 0;
        int iBackgroundStateID = 0;
        {
            if ((pUDMI->dis.itemState & ODS_INACTIVE) | (pUDMI->dis.itemState & ODS_DEFAULT)) {
                // normal display
                iTextStateID = MPI_NORMAL;
                iBackgroundStateID = MPI_NORMAL;
            }
            if (pUDMI->dis.itemState & ODS_HOTLIGHT) {
                // hot tracking
                iTextStateID = MPI_HOT;
                iBackgroundStateID = MPI_HOT;
                pbrBackground = &g_brItemBackgroundHot;
            }
            if (pUDMI->dis.itemState & ODS_SELECTED) {
                // clicked -- MENU_POPUPITEM has no state for this, though MENU_BARITEM does
                iTextStateID = MPI_HOT;
                iBackgroundStateID = MPI_HOT;
                pbrBackground = &g_brItemBackgroundSelected;
            }
            if ((pUDMI->dis.itemState & ODS_GRAYED) || (pUDMI->dis.itemState & ODS_DISABLED)) {
                // disabled / grey text
                iTextStateID = MPI_DISABLED;
                iBackgroundStateID = MPI_DISABLED;
            }
            if (pUDMI->dis.itemState & ODS_NOACCEL) {
                dwFlags |= DT_HIDEPREFIX;
            }
        }
        if (!g_menuTheme) {
            g_menuTheme = OpenThemeData(hWnd, L"Menu");
        }

        DTTOPTS opts = { sizeof(opts), DTT_TEXTCOLOR, iTextStateID != MPI_DISABLED ? RGB(0x00, 0x00, 0x20) : RGB(0x40, 0x40, 0x40) };
        FillRect(pUDMI->um.hdc, &pUDMI->dis.rcItem, *pbrBackground);
        DrawThemeTextEx(g_menuTheme, pUDMI->um.hdc, MENU_BARITEM, MBI_NORMAL, menuString, mii.cch, dwFlags, &pUDMI->dis.rcItem, &opts);
        return true;
    }
    case WM_UAHMEASUREMENUITEM:
    {
        UAHMEASUREMENUITEM* pMmi = (UAHMEASUREMENUITEM*)lParam;

        // allow the default window procedure to handle the message
        // since we don't really care about changing the width
        *lr = DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        // but we can modify it here to make it 1/3rd wider for example
        pMmi->mis.itemWidth = (pMmi->mis.itemWidth * 4) / 3;
        return true;
    }
    case WM_THEMECHANGED:
    {
        if (g_menuTheme) {
            CloseThemeData(g_menuTheme);
            g_menuTheme = nullptr;
        }
        // continue processing in main wndproc
        return false;
    }
    case WM_NCPAINT:
    case WM_NCACTIVATE:
        *lr = DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        UAHDrawMenuNCBottomLine(hWnd);
        return true;
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT lr = 0;
    if (UAHWndProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam, &lr)) {
        return lr;
    }
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

This is "UAHMenuBar.h":

```
#pragma once
#include<windows.h>
// processes messages related to UAH / custom menubar drawing.
// return true if handled, false to continue with normal processing in your wndproc
bool UAHWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* lr);

// window messages related to menu bar drawing
#define WM_UAHDESTROYWINDOW    0x0090   // handled by DefWindowProc
#define WM_UAHDRAWMENU         0x0091   // lParam is UAHMENU
#define WM_UAHDRAWMENUITEM     0x0092   // lParam is UAHDRAWMENUITEM
#define WM_UAHINITMENU         0x0093   // handled by DefWindowProc
#define WM_UAHMEASUREMENUITEM  0x0094   // lParam is UAHMEASUREMENUITEM
#define WM_UAHNCPAINTMENUPOPUP 0x0095   // handled by DefWindowProc

// describes the sizes of the menu bar or menu item
typedef union tagUAHMENUITEMMETRICS
{
    // cx appears to be 14 / 0xE less than rcItem's width!
    // cy 0x14 seems stable, i wonder if it is 4 less than rcItem's height which is always 24 atm
    struct {
        DWORD cx;
        DWORD cy;
    } rgsizeBar[2];
    struct {
        DWORD cx;
        DWORD cy;
    } rgsizePopup[4];
} UAHMENUITEMMETRICS;

// not really used in our case but part of the other structures
typedef struct tagUAHMENUPOPUPMETRICS
{
    DWORD rgcx[4];
    DWORD fUpdateMaxWidths : 2; // from kernel symbols, padded to full dword
} UAHMENUPOPUPMETRICS;

// hmenu is the main window menu; hdc is the context to draw in
typedef struct tagUAHMENU
{
    HMENU hmenu;
    HDC hdc;
    DWORD dwFlags; // no idea what these mean, in my testing it's either 0x00000a00 or sometimes 0x00000a10
} UAHMENU;

// menu items are always referred to by iPosition here
typedef struct tagUAHMENUITEM
{
    int iPosition; // 0-based position of menu item in menubar
    UAHMENUITEMMETRICS umim;
    UAHMENUPOPUPMETRICS umpm;
} UAHMENUITEM;

// the DRAWITEMSTRUCT contains the states of the menu items, as well as
// the position index of the item in the menu, which is duplicated in
// the UAHMENUITEM's iPosition as well
typedef struct UAHDRAWMENUITEM
{
    DRAWITEMSTRUCT dis; // itemID looks uninitialized
    UAHMENU um;
    UAHMENUITEM umi;
} UAHDRAWMENUITEM;

// the MEASUREITEMSTRUCT is intended to be filled with the size of the item
// height appears to be ignored, but width can be modified
typedef struct tagUAHMEASUREMENUITEM
{
    MEASUREITEMSTRUCT mis;
    UAHMENU um;
    UAHMENUITEM umi;
} UAHMEASUREMENUITEM;
#pragma once
```

Comment: Thanks Torrecto, I'll look at all that.   Of course I was hoping I could do it with just a couple more API calls :-(    but sometimes the truth is more complicated.

Comment: @JimHughes If this is what you want. Please accept the answer.